# Spring Security 5 with Google OAuth Redirection Loop

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am using Spring Security 5 with Google OAuth API. I would like all my `/user/**` requests to be authenticated, and if not redirect. My Spring Boot application is running at `localhost:<BackEndPort>` and my frontend (React) running at `localhost:<FrontEndPort>`.

My Backend filter on authentication code:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers("/user/**").authenticated()
                                                                .anyRequest().permitAll())
                   .oauth2Login().and().build();
    }
}
```

My `application.properties` configuration:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=openid,email,profile
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.authorization-uri=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.token-uri=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.user-info-uri=https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.user-name-attribute=name
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.redirect-uri=http://localhost:${server.port}/user/
```

And in my Google API Console I configured redirect URI to `localhost:<BackEndPort>/user/`.

Two questions:

1. Currently, accessing `localhost:<BackEndPort>/user/` redirects me to the Google OAuth page of choosing an account. However, after choosing I am redirected to the same page, and am forever stuck :( How should I change the `configure` function?
2. My frontend that initiates the request to backend (GET `localhost:<BackEndPort>/user/` for user information in this case) receives a CORS restriction even though I added `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:<FrontEndPort>")` at my `/user/` Controller class. Deleting the `SecurityConfig` class erases the CORS restriction...?